# NativeScript - Not getting any response from back-end with patch on NotFound()

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nativescript, backend

On my *back-end* I got two possible responses within that action.

The first one:

```
return Ok(new { Message = "email_confirmed" });
```

And the second one:

```
return NotFound();
```

And on my *front-end* I got this:

```
let url: string = "http://10.0.2.2:53286/api/Home/AccountValidation?codeActivation=" + this.code;

        this.http.patch(url, {

        }).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

            if(res.status != 404) {
                alert({title: "Sistema 3 Esferas", message: "¡Tu cuenta ha sido activada satisfactoriamente! :)", okButtonText: "¡Entendido!"});
                this.router.navigate(["/Miembro"]);
            } else {
                this.btnEnabled = true;
                alert({title: "Sistema 3 Esferas", message: "Has introducido un código inválido. :(", okButtonText: "Entiendo..."});
            }
        });
```

If the *back-end* reaches the `Ok()`, then the `if` gets executed and everything works perfectly. 
However, if my *back-end* reaches the second return, which is the `NotFound()` one, nothing happens. You see this `log` at the beginning of the `subscribe()`?

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Well, if `NotFound()` is returned, nothing is showed on the log. It's almost like if the subscribe was never executed.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add catch handler to catch all other responses than `200(OK)` because they are treated as errors, like this -

```
this.http.patch(url, {

    }).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            alert({title: "Sistema 3 Esferas", message: "¡Tu cuenta ha sido activada satisfactoriamente! :)", okButtonText: "¡Entendido!"});
            this.router.navigate(["/Miembro"]);
    }).catch(this.handleError);
};

private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);

    this.btnEnabled = true;
            alert({title: "Sistema 3 Esferas", message: "Has introducido un código inválido. :(", okButtonText: "Entiendo..."});
}
```

For more information, refer to [this](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-http-patch-with-complex-object-using-observable-in-angular-2-application/).